# Stopwatch inconsistent behavior when initialized using StartNew()

Tags: c#, stopwatch

Doing some performance tests I find the following behavior that seems wrong or counterintuitive.

Does anyone know what can be due?

The following occurs:
If I initialize a watch with StartNew() the results seem inconsistent.
The same is not true if I create an instance of StopWatch.
I leave a sample to reproduce the case with an integer sort function.

Incongruous case:

```
int[] orderedArray = new int[1000000];
int[] unorderedArray = new int[1000000];

for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
{
    orderedArray[i] = i;
}
for (int i = 999999; i > -1; i--)
{
    unorderedArray[i] = i;
}

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine($"Init: {nameof(orderedArray)}");
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Array.Sort(orderedArray);
watch.Stop();
long elapsedTicks = watch.ElapsedTicks;
long elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine($"End: {nameof(orderedArray)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(orderedArray)}|{elapsedTicks} ticks|{elapsedMs} ms");

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

Console.WriteLine($"Init: {nameof(unorderedArray)}");
watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Array.Sort(unorderedArray);
watch.Stop();
elapsedTicks = watch.ElapsedTicks;
elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine($"End: {nameof(unorderedArray)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(unorderedArray)}|{elapsedTicks} ticks|{elapsedMs} ms");
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
```

Correct case (using a new instance of StopWatch then Start-Stop):

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine($"Init: {nameof(orderedArray)}");
Stopwatch watch2 = new();
watch2.Start();
Array.Sort(orderedArray);
watch2.Stop();
long elapsedTicks2 = watch2.ElapsedTicks;
long elapsedMs2 = watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine($"End: {nameof(orderedArray)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(orderedArray)}|{elapsedTicks2} ticks|{elapsedMs2} ms");

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

Console.WriteLine($"Init: {nameof(unorderedArray)}");
watch2.Reset();
watch2.Start();
Array.Sort(unorderedArray);
watch2.Stop();
elapsedTicks2 = watch2.ElapsedTicks;
elapsedMs2 = watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine($"End: {nameof(unorderedArray)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(unorderedArray)}|{elapsedTicks2} ticks|{elapsedMs2} ms");
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
```

Results:

```
Init: orderedArray
End: orderedArray
orderedArray|129247 ticks|12 ms

Init: unorderedArray
End: unorderedArray
unorderedArray|63792 ticks|6 ms

Init: orderedArray
End: orderedArray
orderedArray|61332 ticks|6 ms

Init: unorderedArray
End: unorderedArray
unorderedArray|73364 ticks|7 ms
```

Put them both in same file you can reproduce directly. ¿What is happening? :)

Edit: By my understanding both should have same output. Actually it is not. And also first case says that best sorting case take more time than worst case. I don't know if it's a bug or some expected behavior of StopWatch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with the results? What do you expect which does not match the output you are getting?

Comment: Same result in both first of all. But actually it is best and worst case of sorting algorithm and first case says best case spends more time. But anyways, results should be same for same thing :). It is a problem in Stopwatch. Im not sure if it's a bug or it is expected behaviour (counterintuitive in my opinion if it's the case). Copy paste and check it, you'll see. I will edit to add some more info of the results.

Comment: Please be scientific in your approach by posting the results of your investigation so that others may compare their results to yours.   Also, how many times do you run your test?  In a loop?  You didn't post how the above code is called.   Did you allow for JITing? Did you allow for initial memory management?  Running something once is insufficient.  If the 2nd listing is actually part of the same process and runs after the first, well thats not a good way to test performance.   Reverse the order of the two and I bet your results are also reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a proper (micro)benchmarking you should look into corresponding tools, like [`BenchmarkDotNet`](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) which is created by people with corresponding expertise.

As for your question - assuming that by "inconsistent" you mean the first sort time output being bigger than the later ones it is not `Stopwatch` issue (just use the `Stopwatch.StartNew` approach second after running `Stopwatch watch2 = new();`) it is related to how .NET is executed - runtime needs to load appropriate assemblies and JIT (Just In Time) compile methods/classes from them on the first usage which will result in the "performance hit" you see for the first sort invocation (see [Managed Execution Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-execution-process) doc).

Comment: It makes sense, that's right. If I change the position then it is "my good case" that becomes bad.

Even so, the results are inconsistent. I guess because as you say it is not the most appropriate tool.

Comment: Found a hack calling Array.Sort() before every other executions.

You know some other?
Thanks for answers @Guru Stron

Comment: @Sam you can perform several "warm up" sorts, and only then do actual measured runs (note that JIT can recompile code several times to optimize it during the app lifetime depending on several heuristics). Also there are other factors like clock precision, etc. But again - tools like `BenchmarkDotNet` already handle that for you.

Comment: @Sam Guru makes good points.  Also, check-out Jetbrains ReSharper.  The tooling suite includes performance and memory analysis and will quickly detect hotspots in your code as well as other things like memory leaks if the occasion calls for it.